# Page.Title same as Site.Title on Hugo Site

Tags: hugo

I am building a website with Hugo.
In the config.toml page there is:

`title = "mySite"`

And in the markdown file for the About page, there is:

`title: About`

This works and results in a browser tab that says, About - mySite.

The problem arises on the home page where the browser tab says, mySite - mySite.

The markdown home page does define title:

`title: long name of post`

Browsing the Hugo files, I see that head.html has the line:

```
<title>{{ if .Page.Title }}{{ .Page.Title }} - {{ end }}{{ .Site.Title }}</title>
```

It appears that .Page.Title = .Site.Title for the home page.
How can I set the home page .Page.Title to be "Home" so that the browser tab of the home page reads, "Home - mySite"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try looking into `.IsHome` page variable (https://gohugo.io/variables/page/).

For the case you are describing, I think this could do the trick:

```
<title>{{ if .IsHome }}Home - {{ else }}{{ if .Page.Title }}{{ .Page.Title }} - {{ end }}{{ end }}{{ .Site.Title }}</title>
```

I didn't have a handy site to quickly test the above template rendering, but make sure there is no space between curly braces and `Home` i.e. `}}Home`, otherwise the space will appear in the `<title>` as well. If there is syntax error above, just write in the comment and I'll edit the code.